# Getting rid of trailing \n in Ansible Jinja2 if statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2, newline

I've been looking at about 10 stackoverflow posts by now and nothing has solved my issue. I am trying to set a variable to either a predefined value or a new generated value. I am using the Ansible Jinja2 if statement for this purpose.

I did try using Jinja2 whitespace controls `({%- -%})` and they work for whitespaces as described. `| trim` didn't work as well. The trailing `\n` still exists.

**Problem:** When using Ansible Jinja2 `if` it keeps adding `"\n"` to the string.

**Sample:**

```
---

- name: Example Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  
  tasks:
    - name: Set password
      set_fact:
        password: "Testing"

    # Supposed to go route {{ password }}
    - name: Set Password 1
      set_fact:
        password1: >
          {% if password is defined -%}
            {{ password }}
          {%- else -%}
            {{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}
          {%- endif %}

    # Supposed to go route {{ lookup... }}
    - name: Set Password 2
      set_fact:
        password2: >
          {% if notexist is defined -%}
            {{ password }}
          {%- else -%}
            {{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}
          {%- endif %}

    # Directly setting password3 via {{ lookup... }}
    - name: Set Password 3
      set_fact:
        password3: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}"

    - name: Output Passwords
      debug:
        msg: "Password1: '{{ password1 }}', Password2: '{{ password2 }}', Password3: '{{ password3 }}'"

...
```

**Output:**

```
TASK [Output Passwords] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Password1: 'Testing\n', Password2: 'DawDj7sXEb\n', Password3: 'F9rHw3StT6'"
}
```

Adding `-` to the if statements does remove whitespaces but not the `'\n'`. I need the string without the newlines.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is resolved.

It was not something that Jinja2 if caused but rather YAML multiline handling `>`. I simply added a `-` to the `>` resulting in `>-` and the `\n` was gone.

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html